# Are these two structures isometric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Do the following Riemannian metrics on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ give us isometric structures?Do they generate the same volume forms? Is $O(n)$ a totally geodesic submanifold with respect to these metrics?

1. The metric with orthonormal frame $A\otimes A$ at each point $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$
2. The metric with orthonormal frame $A\otimes A^{tr}$  for $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Note that the tangent space $T_A GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  at each point $A$ is identified with $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ hence with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.(Note that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is counted as an open subset of Euclidean space hence has trivial tangent bundle so the above identification has an obvious desribtion). So at each point $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, each column of the tensor product matrix $A\otimes A$ (or $A\otimes A^{tr}$) can be considered as a tangent vector in $T_A GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. So $A\otimes A$ is obviously a fram, that is a base for the tangent space.This frame define a unique well defined Riemannian metric on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

**Edit:** According to the comments on this question we clarify the identification $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$:
The identification is based on the lexicographic order on the index $i,j$ in $(a_{ij})$. For example $$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$

is identified with $$(a_{11}, a_{12},a_{21}, a_{22})$$

**Remark:** For a homotopic version of this question please see [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349671/homotopicity-of-two-certain-sections-of-frame-bundle-of-gln-mathbbr).

Comment: Could you (or someone else) provide a more detailed explanation of what you mean by #1? I also don't understand #2, but I'm assuming that your explanation of #1 will also clarify #2.

Comment: @DeaneYang  Thank you for your attention to my question. A metric is uniquly determined if we introduce an orthonormal frame. At each point $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ , we introduce  $n^2$ independent tangent vectors to $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ at $A$.Theses $n^2$ vectors are the columns of the matrix $A\otimes A$ for the first metric and $A\otimes A^{tr}$ for the second meyric. Here "tr" is "transpos".

Comment: Given a matrix $A$, could you provide a explicit list of the $n^2$ tangent vectors that form an orthonormal basis? Just the $n=2$ case would be good enough.

Comment: @DeaneYang The columns  of $A\otimes A$ determines $n^2$ independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \simeq T_A GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Right?

Comment: Given a $2$-by-$2$ matrix $A$, could you write down $4$ matrices that would be an orthonormal basis of $T_AGL(n)$?

Comment: @DeaneYang we already identify $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Now please see my previous comment.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: please give an explicit example. Quite possibly the identification you have in mind for identifying $2\times 2$ matrix $(a,b; c,d)$ with a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ sends the matrix to $(a,b,c,d)$. But it could equally well send to $(a,d,c,b)$ or any other combination. The identification can even depend on your position on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. That piece of information maybe in your head, but it is not given to us.

Comment: Ali Taghavi, I still don't understand your replies. It would be very helpful if, given a matrix $A = [ a_{11} a_{12} ; a_{21} a_{22}]$, you could provide explicit formulas for the 4 columns of $A\otimes A$.

Comment: @DeaneYang  My apologies for my delay in response.I explained the identificatiom.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for your attention on my question. My apologies for my delay in response. I add an edit. The delay was because i did not access to computer yester day but i had accecc to my phon and typing was difficult.

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't be able to help any more with this.

Comment: @DeaneYang  Could I clarify the question after the last edit?Thanks again for your attention to my question?

Comment: You still have not provided an orthonormal basis of tangent vectors. Do you intend that  $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_AGL(n)$?

Comment: @DeaneYang  I think  I  provided  the  orthonormal  base. For the  first  metric, it is  the columns  of  $A \otimes A$. Now is  the question, clear?

Comment: @DeaneYang   In this  metric. the  inner  product of  every two  vectors(say the  standard vectors)  $e_i,e_j$ is  equal to $e_i^{tr} (B^{tr})^{-1}B^{-1}e_j$  where  $B=A\otimes A$.  Now is my  question, clear now?

Comment: Could you say more about why you find this particular metric interesting and want to study it? Since your questions can in principle be answered by a straightforward calculation, I'm not sure it is a research level question. Can you say more about what prevents you from doing this calculation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Corrected answer:**  Well, technically, my answers to the OP's questions have not changed, but my argument has changed because I found a silly mistake in my original argument (which I will explain below).

First, computation shows that the first metric, described by giving the orthonormal frame as $A\otimes A$, can be written more conventionally as the symmetric quadratic differential form
$$
ds^2_1 = \mathrm{tr}\bigl( (^{T}\!\!A^{-1}\mathrm{d}A\,A^{-1})\circ(^{T}\!A^{-1}\,{^T}\!(\mathrm{d}A)\,A^{-1})\bigr),
$$
where $A:\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the inclusion mapping.  (N.B.: I use ${^T}\!\!B$ to mean the transpose of $B$.)  Note that this metric is invariant under the left action of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ on $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ given by $R\cdot A = RAR^{-1}$, though it is not invariant under the action of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ by either left or right multiplication.
Direct computation shows that this metric is not flat.  This is most easily carried out by making the substitution $A = B^{-1}$, for, in the $B$-coordinate, the metric becomes
$$
ds^2_1 = \mathrm{tr}\bigl( (^{T}\!\!B\,B^{-1}\mathrm{d}B)\ \circ\ ^{T}\!(^{T}\!\!B\,B^{-1}\mathrm{d}B)\bigr),
$$
which is somewhat simpler to work with.  In fact, the $n^2$ components of the matrix $(^{T}\!\!B\,B^{-1}\mathrm{d}B)$ are an orthonormal basis for the $1$-forms for this metric on $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.  Using this, it's not very hard to compute the curvature matrix and see that it is nonzero.  Moreover, when $n=2$, one can compute the Ricci tensor of $ds^2_1$, and one finds that the four symmetric functions of its eigenvalues, $s_1$ (the scalar curvature), $s_2$, $s_3$, and $s_4$ have the property that $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$ are independent functions on a dense open set in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ while there is a nonzero polynomial $P_1$ of $4$ variables such that $P_1(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$ vanishes identically. (It's not surprising that there would be at least one relation because there is a $1$-dimensional symmetry group of this metric, the $O(2)$-mentioned above.)

Meanwhile, the formula for the second metric, described by giving the orthonormal frame as $A\otimes {}^T\!\!A$, turns out to be more conventionally expressed in the form
$$
ds^2_2 = \mathrm{tr}\bigl( (^{T}\!\!A^{-1}\mathrm{d}A\,^{T}\!\!A^{-1})\circ(A^{-1}\,{^T}\!(\mathrm{d}A)\,A^{-1})\bigr),
$$
*not* as I originally had it, which was
$$
\mathrm{tr}\bigl( (A^{-1}\mathrm{d}A\,A^{-1})\circ(^{T}\!\!A^{-1}\,{^T}\!(\mathrm{d}A)\,^{T}\!\!A^{-1})\bigr)
=\mathrm{tr}\bigl( (\mathrm{d}A^{-1})\ \circ\ ^{T}(\mathrm{d}A^{-1})\bigr).
$$
This latter metric, call it $ds^2_3$, is instead associated to the orthonormal frame field ${}^T\!\!A\otimes A$, and, as the formula above shows when one substitutes $A = B^{-1}$, this third metric is flat.

Unfortunately, $ds^2_2$ is *not* flat, so it is not immediately obvious whether $ds^2_1$ and $ds^2_2$ are isometric.  (They certainly are not *equal*, but it's not immediately obvious that one can't be pulled back to the other by some complicated diffeomorphism.)  However, in the case, $n=2$, one can, by a messy calculation using MAPLE, verify that, if $s_1'$, $s_2'$, $s_3'$ and $s_4'$ are the symmetric functions of the eigenvalues of the Ricci tensor of $ds^2_2$, then $P_1(s_1',s_2',s_3',s_4')$ does *not* vanish identically.  Consequently, $ds^2_1$ and $ds^2_2$ are not isometric when $n=2$.

The two metrics do have the same volume form, but a more involved argument similar to the above works for all $n\ge 2$ to show that they are not isometric, even locally.

Finally, $\mathrm{O}(n)$ cannot be totally geodesic in either metric.  The fact that both metrics are homogeneous of degree $-2$ under the scaling $A\mapsto \lambda A$ shows that there are no compact minimal submanifolds in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ endowed with either metric, let alone totally geodesic ones.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Bryant for your answer.

Comment: (a) Maybe the reference to the flat metric should also be edited in the final paragraph? (b) I am confused about the MAPLE verification: What is the notation $P_1$ in the part about the MAPLE computation? Aren't $s_1'$ etc scalar functions on the manifold? So is the comparison you are making still under the identity map? Then why is it not enough that with respect to the common coordinate systems the two metrics are not equal?

Comment: @WillieWong:  Thanks for your comment.  Yes, I will remove the spurious reference to the flat metric in the last paragraph.  $P_1$ is just what I described: A nonzero polynomial in 4 variables; it's the same one in both mentions.  (It has more than 1000 terms, by the way.)  As for the comparison, no, the point is that *any* (local) diffeomorphism pulling back $ds^2_2$ to $ds^2_1$ (i.e., an isometry), would have to pull back $s_i'$ to $s_i$.  (The converse need not be true.)  Thus, it would have to pull back the function $P_1(s_1',s_2',s_3',s_4')$ (which vanishes only on a hypersurface) to $0$.

Comment: Ah, it is the same $P_1$. Now I completely understand; this also explains what you mean by the word "locally". For higher dimensions, is it then the case that thinking of Riemann as a linear map on two forms, the first metric also has non-trivial relation between the (symmetric functions of) eigenvalues? (Thinking about what you mean by the "more involved argument".)

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes. Because the eigenvalues of Riemann as a linear map are differential invariants of the metric, they are constant on the orbits of the isometry group, which, it turns out, is the group $\mathrm{O}(n)$, and the generic orbit has dimension $\tfrac12n(n{-}1)$. Thus, at most $\tfrac12n(n{+}1)$ differential invariants could be independent functions, and, in fact, that's exactly how many are independent in general. The *relations* satisfied by any larger number of invariants is an isometry invariant of the metric and may be used to distinguish the two metrics.  This is messy, though.